# Как сгенерировать рандом строку в определенной форме?

Tags: php

Нужна строка вот такого вида:

```
ef3ee624-6bcc-4e27-3b43-e64fd4d5c9da
```

А точнее, чтобы она генерировалась случайно и именно в такой последовательности.

Comment: Должна быть уникальной?

Comment: @entithat Вообще, это не очень важно, я делаю это через `str_shuffle`. Мне нужен паттерн для указанной формы.

Comment: Можно просто `md5` чего-либо на части нужные разбить.

Comment: @entithat спасибо, то что нужно

Comment: @entithat, оформите ответ, с примером.

Comment: @sanmai пришлось откатить вашу правку, так как [автору нужен не UUID](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1002649/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b5-php#comment1697865_1002660)

Comment: Таким образом можно сказать что здесь вообще непонятно что спрашивается, и что этот вопрос не будет вообще никому полезен кроме самого автора. Ведь кому ещё нужна случайная строка в какой-то загадочной уникальной форме, которая даже не имеет названия? Правильно, никому.

Comment: @sanmai Сейчас создам вопрос с созданием строки уникального типа))) Но я просто решил проверять на уникальность в БД, так что не знаю какой в этом смысл.

Comment: @RoofLee, как говорится в [одном из ответов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040240/php-function-to-generate-v4-uuid#comment21536414_2040279) к генерации uuid 4 версии, *This function will create duplicates, so avoid it when you need unique values.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Саму строку можно сгенерировать так:

```
// Длинна частей
$array = [8, 4, 4, 4, 12];

// Для каждой такой длинны генерируем случайную строку
foreach ($array as $key => $len) {
    $array[$key] = substr(md5(mt_rand()), 0, $len); 
}

// Вывод: 37e0ec3a-a949-d3a8-28bd-e6502f91ae30
print_r(implode('-', $array));
```

Но мы не можем утверджать, что это UUID, поскольку эта строка не построена согласно правил генерации **UUID**.

Для генерации полноценного **UUID** вы можете использовать [готовые библиотеки](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid) либо посмотреть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040240/php-function-to-generate-v4-uuid) другие варианты реализации.

## UPD

[Универсальный уникальный идентификатор (UUID)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID), представляет собой 128-битное значение, отформатированное в блоки шестнадцатеричных цифр, разделенных дефисом. Типичным **UUID** является `AA97B177-9383-4934-8543-0F91A7A02836`. Не имеет значения, являются ли буквы `A-F` прописными или строчными.

**UUID версии 4** определен в [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122): 128 случайно сгенерированных битов с шестью битами в определенных положениях, установленных на конкретные значения. Например,

```
AA97B177-9383-4934-8543-0F91A7A02836
              ^    ^
              1    2
```

Цифра в позиции 1 выше - это всегда `4`, а цифра в позиции 2 - это всегда `8`, `9`, `A` или `B`.

Процедуру генерации UUID версии 4 можно увидеть [здесь](https://www.cryptosys.net/pki/uuid-rfc4122.html). Как уже было сказано несколько раз, лучше использовать готовые и протестированые библиотеки с реализацией генерации UUID.

Comment: Это не UUID, потому что не содержит чётко прописанных версии и варианта.

Comment: @andreymal мне подходит этот вариант, все нормально